# What is the Web API routing syntax for an array?

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing

If one of the parameters in my web service method is an array (an array of Guids in my case) then what is the correct routing syntax? Here's what I have:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getitems/{companyId:Guid}/{itemIds}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItems(Guid companyId, [FromUri] Guid[] itemIds)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

However, when I send an array to the web method, itemIds is just a single Guid.Empty.

edit 1: the client sends the request like this:

```
string url = $"{_dataServiceBaseUrl}api/v2/getitems/{companyId}/{itemIds}";
var response = dataServiceClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

Comment: If you really need them in the URL, then you'd need to write a model binder that can account for a comma-separated list (or however you want to format them). Otherwise, you can include them as a part of the querystring. The querystring would be that parameter name with an indexer (e.g. `?itemIds[0]=one&itemIds[1]=two`).

Comment: I'm using a HttpClient object on the client side. Is there a better way for me to send the array to the web method?

Comment: I added the client code to the OP.